# Allow (add) my personal gmail account as admin to Google apps for EDU

Tags: google-apps

Our school has google apps for work.The admin account is as  admin@schooldomain.com which is operated by me.
  I also have my personal G-mail account  myname@gmail.com 
  Now I would like to add myname@gmail.com account as admin user in our school domain. 
 how can I achieve it?

I searched a lot for this but not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only access the Admin console with a Google Apps account.